# Php remove single quote from string

Tags: php, escaping, single-quotes

Breaking my head here.
I'm getting data from a website.

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://somepage.com/example');
```

I use the following to search for data I want to filter out the information:

```
preg_match('/class="accent no-margin-bottom inline">(.*?)</', $page, $match);
```

The value I'm getting is : $ 9'858'470, which is what I want.
I would expect this to be a string value. Since I want to insert this data into a database I would like to remove the $ sign and the single quotes.
I'm trying it this way:

```
$replacechars = array ("\'", "$");
echo $string = str_replace($replacechars, "", $match[1]);
```

This returns: 9'858'470

I don't understand why I still see the single quotes.

When I just put

```
$string2 = "9'858'470";
$replacechars = array ("'", "$");
echo $string2 = str_replace($replacechars, "", $string2);
```

It works. Is there a problem with the value filtered from the webpage?

Updated with my code.

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://swissborg.com/chsb-overview');
$replacechars = array ("'", "$");
preg_match('/class="accent no-margin-bottom inline">(.*?)</', $html, $match);
//echo "<BR>";
var_dump($match[1]);
echo "<BR>";
$string = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", strip_tags(html_entity_decode($match[1])));
var_dump($string);


?>
```

Comment: You don't need to escape a single-quote in a double-quoted string, try just using `array ("'", "$");`

Comment: Side note : Don't use RegEx to parse HTML. The day the response will have something like `class="accent no-margin-bottom inline" id="42">` your pattern won't work anymore. Same goes for `class="accent no-margin-bottom inline">foo <span>bar</span> hello world</...`. [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) works pretty good

Comment: array ("'", "$");
Doesn't work. the single quote doesn't get removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think escaping the single quote would work in str_replace where you're using double quotes to wrap the needle values - I'd be tempted as you want just the numbers to go with:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $match[1]);
```

As a more reliable approach.

Alternatively if you're confident that the single quote and $ are the only characters to strip just remove your \ in the array so you're looking for just "'" rather than "'"

UPDATE:

Try removing htmlentities & any tags first to be safe:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", strip_tags(html_entity_decode($match[1])));
```

UPDATE 2:

The below code will work for you and strips the HTML entity  which was representing the quote mark.

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://swissborg.com/chsb-overview');
$replacechars = array ("'", "$");
preg_match('/class="accent no-margin-bottom inline">(.*?)</', $html, $match);
//echo "<BR>";
echo "<BR>";
$string = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$match[1]);
var_dump($string);
```

For future similar issues you can see the actual content, hidden content and all when debugging using json_encode / htmlspecialchars. e.g.:

```
echo json_encode(htmlspecialchars($match[1]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, now the single quote is replaced with 27.
So now I see 92785827470 instead of 9'858'470

Comment: What is output if you var_dump($match[1]) ?

Comment: string(20) " 9'858'470"

Comment: Ahh the string you're seeing must be HTML encoded I think. updating my answer now...

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now I'm getting the 27 again. Updated my code. You can copy directly.

Comment: Thanks for giving the full code - a working solution is under UPDATE 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
$replacechars = array ("'", "$");
```

not this

```
$replacechars = array ("\'", "$");
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) :)

Comment: The suggested solution doesn't work. It seems there is something strange with the string retrieved from the webpage.